# How can I extract rows from large spreadsheet based on condition(s)

Tags: excel-2010

I am scheduling games for a large basketball camp.  The master spreadsheet will looks as follows:

```
TIME    GYM      TEAM A   TEAM B
9:00    MCLELLAN    1   3
9:00    PRACTICE    2   4
9:00    MCKENZIE    5   6
9:00    ABC SCHOOL  6   1
9:00    HOME GYM    2   3
10:00   XYA SCHOOL  4   5
11:00   MCLLELLAN   1   2
12:00   PRACTICE    3   4
1:00    PRACTICE    5   6
```

After completing the master schedule though, I want to be able to automatically extract each team's games independently.  For example, something like this for Team 1:

```
TIME    GYM     TEAM A   TEAM B
9:00    MCLELLAN    1   3
9:00    ABC SCHOOL  6   1
11:00   MCLLELLAN   1   2
```

There will be approximately 40 teams and about 200 games total to work with.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a formula in column E that contains:

`=IF(OR(C2=X,D2=X),1,"")`

where `X` equals the team number. Then you can fill down through all 200 games. Then you need to Filter on Column E where it equals 1 to view all the games for team `X`